# MySQL query to get min field data with timestamp equal to current date

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I have the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(myColumn) as myColumn
FROM myTable
WHERE date(time_stamp) = curdate() AND id = 1;
```

This currently works but is really slow when there is a lot of data present in the database.
I tried it using this:

```
SELECT MIN(myColumn) as myColumn
FROM myTable
WHERE time_stamp >= (now() - interval 1 day) AND id = 1;
```

This query is pretty fast but the problem is i'm getting data for the past 24 hours instead of just the current day as of 12AM.  I'm assuming the date() conversion is slowing it down a lot. Is there a better way to do the first query to speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way can be

```
SELECT MIN(myColumn) as myColumn 
FROM myTable 
WHERE time_stamp between date(now()) and date(now() + interval 1 day) AND id = 1;
```

or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySql installed to test the options but try time_stamp >= curDate()  or modify curDate() to be formatted like a time_stamp.